# Webaii ConfirmDialog missing?

Tags: asp.net, web-testing, webaii

How do you Webaii guys out there handle javascript confirm popup's?

I can't find a ConfirmDialog class in ArtOfTest.WebAii.Win32.Dialogs, and if I try to use AlertDialog instead I get an ArgumentException due to validation rules in the ctor for the AlertDialog class: 
"System.ArgumentException : Alert dialog can only be dismissed using an OK or CLOSE buttons"

### My codesnippet:

Manager.DialogMonitor.AddDialog(new AlertDialog(ActiveBrowser, DialogButton.CANCEL));
Manager.DialogMonitor.Start();

Answer (score 1):

You can do your own custom dialog handling in WebAii:

http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/write-tests-in-code/advanced-topics/handling-html-popups-and-dialogs/built-in-dialog-handlers/custom-dialog-handler.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Actually your problem is that the alert dialog is missing.

So you need to add something like this to ignote the unexpected dialog handlers:

```
myManager.Settings.UnexpectedDialogAction = UnexpectedDialogAction.DoNotHandle;
```

Add the previous code **before** you click on the element which trigger the alert box.